# Mira shower head broke off

Tags: shower

The shower head broke off, and there's nothing to grab onto to unscrew it. I plan to replace the shower head, but do I have to replace the hose as well? Or is there a way to get the plastic bit out?

[image]

**EDIT:** I was reluctant to replace the hose because if something went wrong (e.g. a connector broke), I would no longer have a functional shower and would instead have an urgent plumbing problem. So I spent a lot of time trying to find reverse pliers, to no avail. I experimented with using a utility knife (dangerous!) to get the plastic out, but had no success with that either. After living with the problem for about a year (I am lazy, but I've also had bad experiences with DIY plumbing), I finally got the courage to *gently* try unscrewing the hose. It was easy, and I was able to replace the hose and shower head.

Comment: Unscrew it from what? I can't tell what I'm looking at in that fuzzy shot.

Comment: Get a whole new head with hose.

Comment: poke the tip of a knife into the end, then spin it around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a new head and hose, it's the easiest choice.
Anyway you can try to push around from the inside of broken hose with ['reversed' pliers](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/upkAAOSwNSxU38vG/s-l1600.jpg) then unscrewing.